# Dotvvm - validation errors clear

Tags: asp.net, dotvvm

I have a form in dotvvm 2.0 application. When I do a postback and it validates a viewmodel with errors it sets a css class of associated control to "invalid" (Validator.InvalidCssClass="is-invalid"). Is it possible to clear those validation errors and set the css class to default?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear validation error from the entire view model in Javascript, you can invoke `dotvvm.validation.clearValidationErrors(dotvvm.viewModelObservables.root)`. To clear error only from a part of the view model, you replace the `dotvvm.viewModelObservables.root` with an expression that returns an ko.observable with your view model inside. For example `dotvvm.validation.clearValidationErrors(ko.contextFor(myElement).$rawData)` will clear error in the data context of the `myElement` DOM element.